# What are the consequences of a real world "Gamer" ability?

Tags: society, rpg

The Gamer ability is an ability which makes the world somewhat like an RPG for you. You have pop up screens, Health bar, stats, touching a book can make you learn everything in that book, killing things gives loot (money and items), you level up, you can gain abilities, train those abilities, you have an "inventory", make parties which you can then talk to through your mind, can see their status, can send private messages, etc...

If millions of people woke up one day with this ability, how would the world change? Would the economy be ruined? Would a caste system develop of those who have the ability and those who don't?

Comment: Do these people re-spawn if they die? Do they "level up", and what are the effects? Can one of them take on an armored platoon and wipe them out single handedly with their +20 damage AR-15? I see _a lot_ of potential societal problems, but you need to outline what exactly the consequences, of say, killing your manager in order to "get a loot drop" would be. Or attacking a police officer with a crowbar because you want a better ranged weapon. Other than actually seeing health bars the real world is already an "RPG". We grind for "gold" at our jobs, and buy "new gear", etc.

Comment: Do you lose normal human abilities? You can level up your abilities and you can also learn everything from a book at a touch but if you spend the day touching every medical textbook do you still fail an attempt at diagnosing a medical problem because you've not actually leveled up skill(medical)?

Comment: Are other effects like PvE or PvP areas enforced so that the norms/newbies have a safe haven?

Comment: Also does that guy working at the slaughterhouse get massive numbers of levelups due to the exp from grinding killing chickens?

Comment: I'd also like to point out that your question is incredibly broad. Figure out some of the aspects of your question which these fine folk are inquiring about and I'll try to answer it.

Comment: @AndreiROM No respawns, but can be raised... Normies have no HP bar and act the same as the real world, so a +20 dmg AR-15 might be something equivalent to a higher caliber or an different type of round in effect, but have the same physical properties.

Comment: @Murphy I don't know what you mean be lose normal human abilities... But learning and using a skill would be different. You might know how to perform a surgery, but have low Surgery skill so perform it badly, but surgery of any type might level this is divided into subtypes which increase the overall type but not as much as the expertise in a given subtype...One thing is certain though, there is an absolute gain when performing the action where in the normal world there might not be.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Probably. Even in RPGs with all PvP there is usually some safe zones like churches, schools, and shops...

Comment: @Murphy I would assume chickens are low level so if that is all they did they'd start getting little to no returns for just killing chickens all day, because there would be too big of a level difference ^.^

Comment: @Durakken I'm referencing a certain flavor of gaming/D&D "logic". in the real world are based on knowledge. In the real world: Someone who knows all the facts in every book in a large medical library might not make a great surgeon but would have all the knowledge needed to diagnose illnesses competently and pick treatments. 

In D&D/game logic they're still only got level 1 "medical" and all the "knowledge" is close to simply being flavor/window dressing with little real effect.

Comment: @Durakken in the real world a blacksmith who makes the same type of sword every day for their whole careers may forever remain not very good at blacksmithing in general while one who makes a few and then reads every book they can on blacksmithing methods of everyt ype will quickly become far far more skilled. In game logic the guy grinding swords quickly soundly beats the other in raw skill and for some reason gains the master level ability to make helmets out of enchanted crocodile teeth or something despite never having practiced with that material or read about it.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to use this answer as a sort of longer comment:

What you're describing is effectively the end of civilization as we know it if enough people are turned into "gamers". In any event, fecal matter is going to hit a rotating impeller.

Why? have you played an MMORPG recently? Have you:

- witnessed high level players hunting down low level players for the pure fun of it?
- witnessed a group of enemy players attacking a "town" and wiping out all other players and NPC guards/vendors purely for the fun of it?
- witnessed players fighting for loot?
- witnessed players griefing one another?

Right. That's why.

The reason we don't bash people over the head and steal their stuff is because there's laws in place. However, if a random number of individuals suddenly get magical powers such as:

- getting "loot drops" from killing other human beings
- increased "stats" from performing said murders
- are able to gain an insane amount of information by simply cracking a book open
- telepathically communicate with one another

Well .. say hello to your new overlords, or at the very least, the new biggest organized crime family of all time.

How do players in an RPG generally feel about NPCs? They're subhuman, right? Well, that's you at that point, and the "gamers" have magical powers which will allow them to completely screw with the world.

Comment: You will get a random loot drop if you bash someone over the head. A few quid, an old iphone, a pair of slightly soiled pants, 20 years in the slammer, that sort of thing.

Comment: @separatrix - rare loot might include a brand new Samsung device, and the keys to a BMW though. Just have to farm the right areas.